# Is the power of the Chaos Gods limited to the extent of the Milky Way Galaxy?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I know the Chaos Gods were birthed due to various things and events that happened in the past (with the exception of Slannesh) which bled into the warp creating each of the chaos gods. That being said since they were created due to the actions and emotions of sentient beings in the milky way galaxy (mostly Humans and the Eldar)  are the Chaos Gods confined to our Galaxy only or can they spread throughout the universe?

Comment: Voting to close this question as the WH40K universe is restricted to the Milky Way and nothing is known about the other galaxies. The question can therefore only be answered by opinions.

Comment: We try to keep this site opinion and assumption free, which is the big difference to other boards like reddit or quora. If a question cannot be answered by backed up and canon information, it is the wrong board to ask. You can e.g. check https://www.reddit.com/r/40kLore/comments/6dk945/are_the_chaos_god_unique_to_the_milky_way/ where they discuss exactly what you ask in the speculative manner that is not suited for SciFi-SE.

Comment: I am not closing it because I don't know the answer. I love digging into questions I don't know the answer to in order to answer them. The only thing currently known from outside the Milky Way: Tyranids are from there. We don't even know if they are from another Galaxy, but only that they enter the Milky Way from outside. Everything else is (currently) speculation. Or, as Lexicanum states it: *The Milky Way Galaxy is the realm in which Warhammer 40,000 takes place.* https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Galaxy